# page redirection with html JS and PHP

Tags: php, html

Hi all I have a page with a nav bar on top with several options like Home, Forms, etc. When any of these nav options are clicked you get redirected to another php page.
**Problem:** 
user clicks on a form notification from the Home (home.php) page, it should redirect them to the correct landing page in this case forms.php and open up the form that they selected. I assume I need to pass the formID somehow so I can open it up in the correct form, but how do I do that?

```
<ul class="mainNav">
                    <li class="nav-one"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-two"><a href="forms.php">Forms</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-three"><a href="dash.php">Dashboard </a></li>

                </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the form ID isn't sensitive data then could you add it as a query string to the link?

i.e.

```
<li class="nav-two"><a href="forms.php?formId=someId">Forms</a></li>
```

you could then access this by using

```
$_GET["formId"])
```

Comment: I see.  I'm going to try that out right now. wait so what would happen if I sent the formID like so forms.php?formId=someId would I be able to remove that when I landed on the forms.php? I ask because forms.php holds all the forms that belong to that person. In other words would having the form ID in the url affect anyof the oter forms?

Comment: If you only want to access one form at a time it should be ok. You would only be using the query parameter to filter with?

Comment: yeah basically. Essentially a user would be on the home page click the notification that pertains to that form and land on the forms.php with the form opened. However they would have a list of all other forms. SO in other words when the user clicks on another form does the paramters remain in the URL?

Comment: When a user clicks on another form you would change the query parameter to the id of the new form